# Typescript custom type with properties of another

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

I want to create a custom type or an interface in typescript which depends on the keys of another interface.

Initial Interface :

```js
interface IModelCollection
{
  Account: typeof Account;
  Session: typeof Session;
  ...
}
```

I want to create another type which will be :

```js
interface ISchemaCollection
{
  Account: ReturnModelType<typeof Account>;
  Session: ReturnModelType<typeof Session>;
  ...
}
```

I've tried the following but I get an error `Type 'T[Key]' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyParamConstructor<any>.`

```js
type TSschemaCollection<T extends object> =
{
  [Key in keyof T]: ReturnModelType<T[Key]>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
type ReturnModelType<T> = any; // Define ReturnModelType based on your requirements

interface ISchemaCollection {
  Account: typeof Account;
  Session: typeof Session;
  // ...
}

type TSschemaCollection<T extends ISchemaCollection> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: ReturnModelType<T[Key]>;
};
```

**Edit**
Update your models and see if this helps.

```
public get Models(): { [Key in keyof T]: ReturnModelType<T[Key]> } {
  const models = this._models as { [Key in keyof T]?: ReturnModelType<T[Key]> };

  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(models).map(([key, model]) => [
      key as keyof T,
      getModelForClass(model as any)
    ])
  );
}
```

Comment: I've tried but now I got the error `Type '{ [k: string]: any; }' in not assignable to type '{ [Key in keyof T]?: ReturnModelType<T[Key]>; }`

Comment: My getter looks like this `public get Models(): { [Key in keyof T]: ReturnModelType<T[Key]> }
  {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this._models).map(([key, model]) => [key, getModelForClass(model as any)]));
  }`

Comment: Updated my post. Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: I've tried a lot of solutions. The one that works is a cast to `{ [Key in keyof T]: ReturnModelType<T[Key]> }`. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Alright, awesome! You're welcome. Glad you got it working.